# Rally Standard Report charts with a black background

Tags: html, rally

I've been using the [standard reports](http://developer.rallydev.com/help/standard-reports) to show iteration burndown and release burn up. The API inserts an image it generates into the page using javascript.

I would like to put these on a dashboard monitor in my office, but it's current colour theme has a black background.

I want charts with a black background. I see a number of options:

- Get the API to generate charts (maybe an undocumented feature)
- Do some HTML-based colour replacement
- Get the underlying data and build my own chart

Is any of the above possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now the charts are server generated images, so to my knowledge there is no way to pass in a parameter controlling the background color or change it once it's loaded.

Soon, however we will be adding new charting capabilities based on the new Analytics 2.0 api.  These will be client side rendered and very configurable and should be able to do what you are describing.

In the meantime though you should be able to get the data that backs those charts through the WSAPI.